# Change ViewModel from Service WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am learning to create a WPF application following the MVVM patern. I'm try change data in viewmodel from service class but it can work, here is example code:

In MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="6">
    <TextBox materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Status"
             Text="{Binding Status, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}"
             VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

In MainViewModel.cs:

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private static MainViewModel _instance = new MainViewModel();
    public static MainViewModel Instance { get { return _instance; } }
    
    //...
    
    // Status
    private string _Status = "Status";
    public string Status { get => _Status; set { _Status = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
    
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ////
        
        
        // => This command can change status
        // Start
        StartCommand = new RelayCommand<object>((p) => { return true; }, (p) =>
        {
            OutStatus("Task success!");
        });

    }
    
    public void OutStatus(string status)
    {
        Status = status;
    }

}
```

In UtilitiesService.cs

```
public static class UtilitiesService{
    public static void SetStatus(){
        // => Here i can't change Status and can't binding to MainWindow.xaml
        MainViewModel.Instance.OutStatus("Change Status in service");
    }
}
```

So how can I change a property in manviewmodel in service file.Sorry Im so noob :))

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with what you've posted (apart from those static members, which you should never do in MVVM, but that's another issue), have you confirmed that OutStatus is in fact being called? You probably need to include your declaration of StartCommand as well.

Comment: Within mainviewmodel you instantiate another mainviewmodel. Which will instantiate another mainviewmodel.... Do not do that.

Answer (score 0):

You are using different instances of `MainViewModel` for data binding and for updating.

Also don't use public static instances or members across the application. Instead directly pass around the instance (in your case `MainViewModel` and `UtilitiesService`).
Generally static class members like properties or fields introduce a potential memory leak, because the garbage collector can't collect them to free memory. It also makes unit testing difficult and defies the concept of object oriented language key features like encapsulation. It will make code hard to modify.

In the simplest scenario, you can create the `MainViewModel` instance in your `MainWindow`. You can also create a shared instance of `UtilitiesService` at this point as well.

It's unclear what purpose `UtilitiesService` has. If it is meant to update `MainViewModel` by other View Model classes you can do it your way. If it is meant to be used in the Model, then you shouldn't do it your way. In this case your `MainVoewModel` would listen to the `UtilitiesService` events to update itself. Because in MVVM the Model does never talk to the View Model.

The recommended C# naming convention suggests to name fields using the *camelCase* pattern (starting with a lower case letter). [Microsoft Docs: Naming Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines#in-this-section)

A `TextBox.Text` binding that is configured to bind `OneWay` is pretty useless. In this case the `TextBox` only serves as display. You should then use `TextBlock` instead.

**MainViewModel.cs**

```cs
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
  //...

  // Status
  private string _status = "Status";
  public string Status { get => _status; set { _status = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

  public MainViewModel()
  {
    ////

    // => This command can change status
    // Start
    StartCommand = new RelayCommand<object>((p) => { return true; }, (p) =>
    {
      SetStatus("Task success!");
    });

  }

  public void SetStatus(string status)
  {
    Status = status;
  }
}
```

**UtilitiesService.cs**

```cs
public class UtilitiesService
{
  private MainViewModel MainViewModel { get; }

  public void UtilitiesService(MainViewModel mainViewModel)
  {
    this.MainViewModel = mainViewModel;
  }

  public void SetStatus()
  {
    // Change MainViewModel.Status and update bindings in MainWindow.xaml
    this.MainViewModel.SetStatus("Change Status in service");
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
 
    var mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();

    this.DataContext = mainViewModel;

    var sharedUtilitiesService = new UtilitiesService(mainViewModel);

    // Pass the shared UtilitiesService instance to other view model classes
    // to allow them to update the MainViewModel anonymously.
    var otherViewModel = new OtherViewModel(sharedUtilitiesService);
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}" />
</Window>
```